# Local json migration: how to set the value of the urls variable?

Tags: migrations

I'm currently really busy to get the migration work on my desk.
I want to import (migrate) a local json file into drupal8 using Migrate_Plus, Migrate tools. 
For that I have the following migration yml configuration file

```
# Migration configuration for products.
id: product
label: 'Product'
migration_group: Products
# Here we define the migration source
source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: file
  data_parser_plugin: json
  urls: /modules/custom/migrate_products/data/data.json
  item_selector: /data
  fields:
    -
      name: uuid
      label: 'uuid'
      selector: uuid/value

    -
     name: name
     label: 'Produkt Name'
     selector: name/value

    -
      name: supplierName
      label: 'Anbietername'
      selector: supplierName/value

  ids:
    uuid:
     type: string



destination:
    plugin: entity:node

process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: produkt

  title: name
  field_uuid: uuid
  field_suppliername: supplierName

  sticky:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 0
  uid:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 0

migration_dependencies:
  required: {}
  optional: {}

dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - migrate_products
```

Like you can see, the json file is located inside the custom module directory.

The json file looks like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "uuid": {
        "value": "7d51-4406-a7ef-3a7916b977a9",
        "patient": false
      },
      "name": {
        "value": "Product1",
        "patient": false
      },
      "supplierName": {
        "value": "User1",
        "patient": false
      },
.....
```

After enbaling the required migration module, when running:
**drush ms**
I get the following output:

```
file parser plugin: could not retrieve data from /modules/custom/migrate_products/data/data.json
 Group: Products (Products)  Status  Total  Imported  Unprocessed  Last imported 
 product                     Idle    n. v.  0         n. v.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data fetcher plugin can't find your JSON file because the format is wrong. The plugin is expecting Drupal's `URI` format (e.g. `public://path/to/data.json` or `private://path/to/data.json`) under its private/public file dir. For example, see the [included example migration](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/migrate_plus/tree/migrate_json_example/config/optional/migrate_plus.migration.product.yml) with the module:

```
  # The data_parser normally limits the fields passed on to the source plugin
  # to fields configured to be used as part of the migration. To support more
  # dynamic migrations, the JSON data parser supports including the original
  # data for the current row. Simply include the 'include_raw_data' flag set
  # to `true` to enable this. This option is disabled by default to minimize
  # memory footprint for migrations that do not need this capability.
  # include_raw_data: true
  # Flags whether to track changes to incoming data. If TRUE, we will maintain
  # hashed source rows to determine whether incoming data has changed.
  # track_changes: true
  # Copy the example JSON file in artifacts folder to sites/default/files folder.
  urls:
    - 'public://migrate_json_example/products.json'
```

Comment: When I try this, I get an error: `Migration failed with source plugin exception: Error message: cURL error 1: Protocol "public" not supported or disabled in libcurl (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) at public://articles/images/images.json.` - any idea what could be the cause?

Comment: It looks like `public://`URI isn't getting translated to the HTTP protocol before it is passed off to cURL for retrieval.

Comment: I am on Docker and what I wanted to achieve ultimately was to retrieve the JSON from a local route which wasn't working either. In the end I found out I had to declare the path as `nginx_back/api/article/images.json` where `nginx_back` is the name of my NGINX container. That works with the `data_fetcher_plugin` set to `http`. Worth noting...